# Map structure supports sorting too?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I am using a map structure in my program. The key for the structure is the timestamp. The values keep on changing randomly. My main intention of using map was to ensure that the representation of all the values along with their timestamp should be in the descending order, like the latest event should come on top. However, this is not happening. The values are not in the desired (descending) order.

I have declared map structure like

```
map<time_t, events> eventR;
map<time_t, events>::iterator iterator;

if the events are there {
then iterator=eventR.begin();
for(iterator = eventR.begin(); iterator!=eventR.end(); ++iterator)
{
//Display
}
}
```

It may be that I have understood map structure wrong, like it doesn't sort necessarily, but I thought if I am using timestamp, so data will be displayed according to latest events. Am I doing something wrong here? Do I have to use different data structure to get desired result?

Thanks

Comment: Are the elements in *any* particular order, or are they completely random?

Comment: which elements are you referring to here? The output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Declare your map as: `std::map<time_t, events, std::greater<time_t>>`. (Use a `typedef` so that it's easier to declare iterators.)

Alternatively, iterate your map in reverse using `rbegin()` and `rend()`.

Comment: I will try it now, but can you shed some light how that will sort it according to latest timestamps? Thanks!

Comment: @UnderDog: The elements of a `std::map` are sorted by key value. By default, the sorting is done according to the `<` predicate; with `std::greater` you use the `>` comparison instead. Rather than reversing the sort order, you can also simply traverse the map in the opposite order using reverse iterators.

Comment: kerrek - when I use rend, it gives an error like "no operator != matches these operands" ..

Comment: Thanks a ton kerrek. I understood the problem. You are right. However, I am facing a bit technical problem here for the reason I mentioned above.

Comment: @UnderDog: The type is `reverse_iterator` -- why don't you look up this fairly standard material on a good [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)? :-)

Comment: Got it! I have to use reverse_iterator.. Thanks.. will let you know if the solutions works out. Wish I could upvote your answer, but dont have the necessary reputation. Thanks again!

Comment: @UnderDog: Either change the compare function when you create the `map` __or__ use `reverse_iterator`. Don't do both because they'll cancel each other out.

Comment: Yeah..looked on some references only :)

Comment: If I am using reverse_iterator method, is it anyway to know if the iterator has reaching the beginning point. As reverse_iterator and normal iterator cannot be compared.

Comment: @UnderDog: If you are using `reverse_iterator` write your loop the same but replace `begin()/end()` with `rbegin()/rend()`.

Answer (score 1):

A c++ std::map does guarantee a certain sorting order:

From: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/

> Internally, the elements in the map are sorted from lower to higher
>   key value following a specific strict weak ordering criterion set on
>   construction.